# NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient! Unit Testing a service

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I have been trying to unit test a basic service today and I keep getting this error: 
`Error: StaticInjectorError[HttpClient]: 
  StaticInjectorError[HttpClient]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient! "Error: StaticInjectorError".`

I have been searching SO and Google for answers and all I find is people suggesting to add HttpClient to your import section of your test bed.

When I add HttpClient to the import section of my test bed I get this error: `Error: Unexpected value 'HttpClient' imported by the module 'DynamicTestModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.`

Here is my code below

Unit Test File:

```
import { VisitsIngestedService } from '../../../xxxx.App/src/app/Services/GetVisitsIngestedService';
import { HttpModule, BaseRequestOptions } from '../../../xxxx.App/node_modules/@angular/http';
import { MockBackend } from '@angular/http/testing';
import { JsonpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { Jsonp } from '@angular/http';
import { TestBed, getTestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';


describe('VisitsIngestedService', () => {
  let injector: TestBed;
  let service: VisitsIngestedService;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [VisitsIngestedService]
    });
    injector = getTestBed();
    service = injector.get(VisitsIngestedService);
    httpMock = injector.get(HttpTestingController);
  });

  describe('#getVisits', () => {
    it('should return an Observable<Vists[]>', () => {
      const dummyVisits = [
        { login: 'John' },
        { login: 'Doe' }
      ];

      service.getVisitsIngested("faketen", "fakedate1", "fakedate2").subscribe(visits => {
        expect(visits.length).toBe(2);
        expect(visits).toEqual(dummyVisits);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Service File:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Visit } from '../Models/Visit';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable()
export class VisitsIngestedService {

  constructor(private _httpService: HttpClient) { }

  public getVisitsIngested(tenant: string, start: string, end: string): Observable<any> {
    return this._httpService.get('/api/appInsights/query/' + tenant + '/' + start + '/' + end);
  }

}
```

App.module.ts file:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { VisitsIngestedService } from '../../../../CloudMedOps.App/src/app/Services/GetVisitsIngestedService';



@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, HttpClient],
  providers: [VisitsIngestedService, HttpClient],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I am new to Angular and would appriciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: Import `HttpClientModule` instead of `HttpClient`.

Comment: @Lotus_8 did you get this answer, as I'm also facing same issue

Answer (score 7):

You need to import

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

and inside imports

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [VisitsIngestedService],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
```

Comment: I tried this and I still am getting the error. I tried commenting out the guts of app.module.ts in both my test project and my app project and to my surprise this did not make a difference and I still have the same error.

Comment: remove HttpClient inside providers

Comment: Still gives me the error after removing HttpClient inside the provider array.